# Attribute routing doesn't work on Put request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my simple WebApi project I'm only using attribute routing by doing this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

I have this controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("myprefix")]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("v2/test/dosomething")]
    public IHttpActionResult TestIt()
    {
        return Ok("Test ok");
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("v2/myaction/somethingelse")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction(string message)
    {
        return Ok("Put ok");
    }
}
```

I'm accessing the above as follows:

```
GET http://localhost/myapp/myprefix/v2/test/dosomething
PUT http://localhost/myapp/myprefix/v2/myaction/somethingelse
```

The `GET` works fine. However, the `PUT` returns:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/myapp/myprefix/v2/myaction/somethingelse'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Some' that matches the request."
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does the Put request work if you remove the message parameter?

Comment: Use fiddler or something like it to inspect the PUT request being sent. Show the raw request/response and maybe it can help narrow down your problem.

Comment: It should not have influence on the routing, but ´MyAction´ is declared async although no await call is made.

Comment: @MarcusH Yes it works without message parameter.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm using Firefox's RestClient to test the api.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, Ok cool. looks like someone already figured it out, which hints at how you are sending the request. which is why I was asking to see the raw request/response message. With your example the error message would be correct if the request was not sent correctly.

Comment: @rboe I removed the code which was doing an await call.

Comment: Great! Than its only a routing problem. Either call the method as is like this: localhost/myapp/myprefix/v2/myaction/somethingelse?message=waasssaa. If that don't work then change it like this MyAction([FromUri]string message). If that don't work then add MyAction([FromBody]string message) and make a put request with a body contain a message value

Comment: @MarcusH In the meantime I put `[FromBody]` to the parameter. However the value is always null.

Comment: But you are then able to make a put request to the method? Please share the code where you create the request and attach the message to the body.

Comment: @MarcusH I'm currently using Firefox RestClient to test the api.

Comment: ok, In the request body field, add: {"message":"waaaasssaaa"} 
And in the request header field, add: Content-Type: 'application/json'

Comment: @MarcusH Same result. message is null.

Comment: Ok, I'll create an answer..One second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default way of sending data with PUT requests are through the body. So first step is to add a [FromBody] infront of the parameter. If you sending data with content type of json then I would create a object as parameter instead which contains a message parameter.

```
public class jsonMessage
{
    public string message {get; set; }
}
```

Use the jsonMessage class as the parameter with the [FromBody] in the controller method as this

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("v2/myaction/somethingelse")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction([FromBody]jsonMessage message)
{
    return Ok("Put ok");
}
```

Then when making request to the endpoint add a request body as this  `{"message":"waaaasssaaa"}` and send it with `Content-Type: 'application/json'`

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPut]
 [Route("v2/myaction/somethingelse/{message}")]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction(string message)
 {
     return Ok("Put ok");
 }
```

Actually you have to specifie your parameter also, in your route.

Comment: Wouldn't this apply if the message parameter is part or the Uri?

Comment: In your example you just have to add {message} parameter in route.... And it will work fine..